# plt.errorbar issue: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graph, warnings, errorbar

When I execute a code like the one below, with plt.errorbar, I get the following warning message:

> FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar
>   instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison   if
>   self._edgecolors == str('face'):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
y = np.array([2,3,5,6,5,4,6,7,2,1])
yerreur = np.array([2,4,5,1,1,3,4,5,2,1])

plt.figure(1)

plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr = yerreur,fmt = 'None',ecolor = 'k')

plt.savefig('test.pdf')

plt.show()
```

How can I fix this issue? Does it affect my graph in any way?

Comment: It does not affect your diagram, is only a warning. I don't see the warning here (python: 3.4.3 + numpy: 1.11.0 + matplotlib: 1.5.1)  Which version are you using?

Comment: I use version 1.4.3.

Comment: I would say it's a [version issue](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/723). Try updating it, I'm pretty sure that will do ;)

Answer (score 1):

This issue was taken care of in version 1.5.x:

> It should be 1.5 was branched from master after this was merged and it is on the 1.5.x branch

[Make sure _edgecolors is a string before comparison to string](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/4925)

Try updating matplotlib to the latest version.